# split fields in pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in pyspark with a filed `value` as below -

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2023-03-05 MONTH   2020M03 2020-03-01  2020-03-31  ADDR    Fargo-Wahpeton, ND-MN   61.30   98.52   433.23                   |
|2023-03-05 MONTH   2020M03 2020-03-01  2020-03-31  STATE   TX  43.38   74.61   380.82                                       |
|2023-03-05 MONTH   2020M03 2020-03-01  2020-03-31  ADDR    Kalamazoo-Battle Creek-Portage, MI  30.19   49.06   266.33       |
|2023-03-05 MONTH   2020M03 2020-03-01  2020-03-31  STATE   TN  11.87   19.92   946.73                                       |
|2023-03-05 MONTH   2020M03 2020-03-01  2020-03-31  ADDR    New York-Newark, NY-NJ-CT-PA    32.24   55.95   322.16           |
|2023-03-05 MONTH   2020M03 2020-03-01  2020-03-31  LOCATION    New England 22.277  42.56   202.76                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, I would like to split the field `value` into several fields as below -

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+--------------+------------------+
|insert_dt  |sub_type  |ret_month  |month_start   |month_end    |area_class         |area_details                           |sub_paid |sub_pending   |sub_annual_amt    |
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+--------------+------------------+
|2023-03-05 |MONTH     |2020M03    |2020-03-01    |2020-03-31   |addr               |Fargo-Wahpeton, ND-MN                  |61.30    |98.52         |433.23            |
|2023-03-05 |MONTH     |2020M03    |2020-03-01    |2020-03-31   |state              |TX                                     |43.38    |74.61         |380.82            |
|2023-03-05 |MONTH     |2020M03    |2020-03-01    |2020-03-31   |addr               |Kalamazoo-Battle Creek-Portage, MI     |30.19    |49.06         |266.33            |
|2023-03-05 |MONTH     |2020M03    |2020-03-01    |2020-03-31   |state              |TN                                     |11.87    |19.92         |946.73            |
|2023-03-05 |MONTH     |2020M03    |2020-03-01    |2020-03-31   |addr               |New York-Newark, NY-NJ-CT-PA           |32.24    |55.95         |322.16            |
|2023-03-05 |MONTH     |2020M03    |2020-03-01    |2020-03-31   |location           |New England                            |22.27    |42.56         |202.76            |
+-----------+----------|-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+--------------+------------------+
```

I tried regex_extract as below but could get this.

```
regex_pattern = r'^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$'

df.select(regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 1).alias('insert_dt'),
          regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 2).alias('sub_type'),
          regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 3).alias('ret_month'),
          regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 4).alias('month_start'),
         regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 5).alias('month_end'),
          regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 6).alias('area_class'),
          regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 7).alias('area_details'),
          regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 8).alias('sub_paid'),
          regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 9).alias('sub_pending'),
          regexp_extract('value', regex_pattern, 10).alias('sub_annual_amt')
          ).display()
```

could someone suggest me a way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add what exactly did you try?

Comment: Added details of my attempt in the question

Comment: Thanks, could you also add what is `regex_pattern` and what error did you get?

Comment: Added regex_pattern

Comment: there was no error but the result looks blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this regex

```py
regex_pattern = r'^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+([^0-9]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)?\s+?(\S+)\s+$'
```

This should group the `area_details` in the same column

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a problem in your regex_pattern, here's a simple solution:

```
regex_pattern = '(?<!,)[\s]+'

columns = ["insert_dt", "sub_type", "ret_month", "month_start", "month_end", "area_class", "area_details",
           "sub_paid", "sub_pending", "sub_annual_amt"]

for idx, column in enumerate(columns):
    df = df.withColumn(column, trim(split("value", regex_pattern).getItem(idx)))
df.show(truncate=False)


+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
|insert_dt |sub_type|ret_month|month_start|month_end |area_class|area_details         |sub_paid         |sub_pending|sub_annual_amt|
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
|2023-03-05|MONTH   |2020M03  |2020-03-01 |2020-03-31|ADDR      |Fargo-Wahpeton, ND-MN|61.30            |98.52      |433.23        |
|2023-03-05|MONTH   |2020M03  |2020-03-01 |2020-03-31|STATE     |TX                   |43.38            |74.61      |380.82        |
|2023-03-05|MONTH   |2020M03  |2020-03-01 |2020-03-31|ADDR      |Kalamazoo-Battle     |Creek-Portage, MI|30.19      |49.06         |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: But, the value of `area_details` are spilled into `sub_paid` and `sub_pending` columns too.

Comment: @bunnylorr I updated my answer again